Flashing JS text with hyperlink
I want flashing text to link to two different pages, and for the background colors to take over the entire page. I'm a novice, any help with JS is appreciated! Or maybe I don't even need JS for this.
Hello!
I'm trying to make a page that flashes between a black bg and white text and a white bg with black text. I want each diff page to be a hyperlink to a separate page. I tried adapting the JS script I had but the flashing only worked the way I wanted to this way. the hyperlink only works with the black bg/white text and when it flashes to white it doesn't take over the whole page like i want it to. i would also like it to not be static and move with the window configurations but the display properties im trying don't seem to work with it. i'm really new to this so any help is greatly appreciated!


       
function timer() {
  let blink2 = document.getElementById("blink2");
  blink2.style.opacity = blink2.style.opacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  setTimeout(timer, 250);
}

timer();
         
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#blink {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: auto;
  max-width: max-content;
}

#blink2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: auto;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: inherit;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}
<body>
  <div>
    <h1 id="blink"><a href="page1.html"> hello </a></h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 id="blink2"><a href="page2.html"> hello </a></h1>
  </div>
</body>




Please format the code as code {} it is difficult to read at the moment. And preferably make it a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@AHaworth Let me know if it is easier to read now!

Could you explain what this means? “ when it flashes to white it doesn't take over the whole page like i want it to. i would also like it to not be static and move with the window configurations ”

I imagine this is just a game as a sort of test, but just to be aware of accessibility issues if it were ever published, such flashing is triggering to some people so an alternative for those who have set prefers-reduced-motion and a way of switching the flashing off should be provided see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

@AHaworth The BG color is set to black, and the script seems to only be working with #blink2. I want the entire background to be white when the text is black, and for the entire background to be black when the text is white. Kind of like two separate pages flashing at an interval. Also, I meant I wanted to have the display be flexible when I resize the browser window.

You can can stretch h1 to cover the page and use a css animation:


body {
  background-color: black;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#blink {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10rem;
  
  /* center <a> */
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  
  animation: blink 250ms infinite;
  
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: inherit;
}


@keyframes blink {
  0%, 49.9% {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  50%, 99.9% {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}
<body>
  <h1 id="blink"><a href="page1.html"> hello </a></h1>
</body>



